# How should I design Cassandra tables?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I've got the following problem: there're some sport groups (say, soccer/tennis) on facebook where the users may be either offline or online. Moreover, each user has some countryId and belongs to exactly 1 sport group.

I'd like to able to:

1. Query for all the user ids and their groupId (given a countryId)
2. Query for all the user ids given a countryId and a groupId.

So basically I need a following table (I set groupId as a clustering key so I'd be able to query for query #1, because I have to specify all values of the partition key):

```
primary key: countryId (partition key), groupId (clustering key)
value column: userId
```

Everything's good so far and now I'd like to change specification:

I'd like to able to:

1. Query for all the **online** user ids and their groupId (given a countryId)
2. Query for all the **online** user ids given a countryId and a groupId.

I receive a notification every time any user change its online/offline status. Essentially I need another table where:

```
primary key: driverId (partition key)
value column (boolean): isOnline
```

I don't want to add this column into my 1st table because I can't directly extract a countryId and groupId from userId. How would you design a database schema then?

Comment: This is a very broad question and as such attracts opinionated answers. Please try to edit this problem down to 1 singular, answerable question that shows your effort you've put into this problem instead of asking us to give you something without context.

Comment: @Jouster500 Edited a question.